# Some questions about using GroundOverlay or TileOverlay to show large overlay image in GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an application where a user can load an image on top of a Google map. This was developed for 2.3, so there is a MapActivity, a MapView and my custom Overlay class that shows the image.
In the overlay class draw-method I recalculate a Matrix each time, so the image gets the correct size and position. I also have a calibration mode where the user can adjust the image by dragging reference points.

I am going to add some features to the application and I want to start with some updates like using fragments. Replacing the MapActivity with MapFragment brings up some question since there doesn't seem to be any support for overlays where you can implement draw by yourself. It seems like I will have to use GroundOverlays or TileOverlay. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Neither of these seems to support any modification of the overlays after they have been added, so the calibration of the image will not work. My plan for that part is to put an ordinary ImageView on top of the MapFragment for the calibration mode. (That will hide all Markers, but that doesn't matter during calibration.) For this to work I need two things:
* Receive all touch events that affects the calibration points and forward the rest to allow normal zoom etc.
* Detect any time the position/rotation/zoom level changes so I can adjust the image.
Question #1: Can I expect any major problems with that?

Then I have to decide if GroundOverlays or TileOverlay is preferrable.

GroundOverlay:
This seems to require the least work since it will still load the whole image. I also think that it will handle things like screen orientation changes automatically.
Question #2: Will the GroundOverlay work well with a large image (max. 2000*2000 pixels)? Is there any copying of the image involved? Because the image is so large I can not afford more than one copy of it in memory.

TileOverlay: 
In a way this seems like a more professional solution because it only uses the parts that are actually needed and I can later introduce support for using several map image sources at the same time.
I will probably have to generate the tiles in advance and save a separate file for each, keeping it in memory and creating the tiles on demand might take to much memory. (Or perhaps I can create a separate tile-serving service but that seems a little dirty.)
Question #3: Is there any control over how much memory the tile caching will use? Does the usual limit apply? I don't want to run out of memory somewhere else in the application just because the cache took most of the memory I'm allowed to use.
Question #4: The documentation says "Note that unlike other overlays, if the map is recreated, tile overlays are not automatically restored and must be re-added manually". I suppose that this will happen on every screen rotation, so that this means that the files will have to be read again causing a noticable loading delay. Is there any good way around this?
Question 5: When getTile is called and I return null (because the tile is saved in a file and I don't want to block the ui thread while reading it), how long will it take until it is requested again? (There doesn't seem to be a way to load an individual tile manually.)
Question 6: How do I determine a good image resolution for one tile image (with respect to performance and quality)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of questions. I'll try to address some.

1. Generally, beware that Maps API v2 is much less permissive than v1. And it's a good thing. v2 has many more built-in functions and optimizations that v1 didn't have, and by having a restrictive API forces you to use its optimizations.
2. For example, if you were using GroundOverlay to display an image [assuming that you don't need to rotate or distort it], you need only specify the Lat/Long bounds of it and Maps v2 will stretch the image for you. 2000x2000 would be 2000x2000x4 bytes so 16MBytes in memory. 
   But GroundOverlayOptions uses a BitmapDescriptor, so maybe it's never fully loading the image in memory. 
   I'm not very familiar with the GroundOverlay.

   The other option is to cut the image in tiles the first time you load it and save them on the local storage, then it's pretty straight-forward to use with TileOverlay. You can't reasonably read the tile directly from the 2kx2k image because it would involve read it all (if compressed, which I guess it is).
   If ever you need to show a modified version of the image, remember that you only need to create a Canvas over the Bitmap, after ensuring it's mutable.
3. I'm more familiar with the TileOverlay which I use a lot. The tiles cache looks fair enough to me, I have loaded big amounts of 256x256 tiles and always stayed between 13M and 20M heap. I think it's using the same as for google map tiles, caching some on the local storage memory but never too much, and not caching at all in memory tiles that aren't shown. You can see when padding that the tiles are being reloaded.

   You can easily see GMaps tiles caching strategy by listing the files of your internal storage. There you'll see GMaps caches tiles.
4. Yes, when stop/starting the GoogleMap will call getTile(x, y, zoom) for each showing tile. Looks like each call to getTile has its own thread, so loading time ins't an issue. If your tiles are already stored on your device it's very fast to load. Really not an issue, provided that you store your data in a smart way.
5. I've never returned null. Don't know what happens in this case. Maybe it fires an exception that is ignored. Note that any runtime exception or even some java.lang.error generated by your code in getTile will be ignored by GoogleMap calls... I've reported to issue here and you might want to apply the patch to ease your development: [https://code.google.com/p/gmap...](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4995)

   To reply to your question, I've returned the "NO_TILE" object, and then GMap caches it like any tile. You can force reloading of the tiles by calling [TileOverlay.clearTileCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay.html#clearTileCache%28%29).
6. I've been thinking of that, but I use only 256x256 tiles and it seems good enough even on the High DPI Nexus 10. I haven't investigated the issue much more, but it might be that GMaps already chooses which tiles would be best to show depending on the zoom level, provided that 256p is quite a standard tile size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it gives me some starting help.